# Перевернуть иконку svg

Tags: svg

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 5 5" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 4.7913519,3.0244664 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 5.0010679,2.7928393 L 5.0156169,0.23844982 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 4.8085546,0.00421882 L 4.1346977,8.822488e-6 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 3.9249817,0.23163592 l -0.01455,2.55438948 a 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 0.2070636,0.2342309 z"/>
    <path d="m 2.3026685,4.9997485 c 0.013054,-4.93e-4 0.026303,-0.00179 0.038974,-0.00367 a 0.41548798,0.46467067 0.20022686 0 0 0.349375,-0.4734803 c 0.00363,-0.6379822 0.449321,-1.333972 0.846806,-1.6370154 a 0.10387201,0.11616766 0.20022683 0 0 0.04533,-0.093674 L 3.5965423,0.44108678 A 0.10387201,0.11616766 0.20022683 0 0 3.5134437,0.3270351 C 3.4393718,0.31054085 3.3726995,0.29427924 3.3092171,0.2787802 A 3.5958408,4.0214923 0.20022685 0 0 2.454861,0.1638249 L 1.1051997,0.15539263 C 0.69865229,0.15285266 0.63632562,0.4085934 0.63546547,0.5596088 A 0.46534654,0.52043115 0.20022685 0 0 0.68283896,0.79088466 0.46700849,0.52228983 0.20022686 0 0 0.4704808,1.4864123 0.46783947,0.52321918 0.20022686 0 0 0.21269657,1.9506762 0.46243812,0.51717845 0.20022685 0 0 0.26776008,2.1996173 0.51935998,0.58083833 0.20022685 0 0 3.9256542e-6,2.7049256 0.51935998,0.58083833 0.20022685 0 0 0.51670335,3.287561 l 1.31071015,0.00819 a 0.051936,0.05808384 0.20022688 0 1 0.048253,0.076641 1.8040488,2.0176 0.20022685 0 0 -0.1129471,1.0230443 c 0.1119192,0.4570286 0.3441218,0.611708 0.5399491,0.6043122 z"/>
</svg>
```

Кто может перевернуть иконку, то есть чтобы сделать из нее лайк, чтобы данный лайк смотрел в туже сторону что и изначально.

Наклонить, вращение это все понятно, но как именно перевернуть ее с низу вверх, чтобы сделать из дизлайка - лайк?

Comment: `svg { transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1); }` или без `scaleX`, если направление устраивает, или сразу `transform: scaleY(-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте атрибут [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) со значением `"scale(1,-1)"`:

```html
<svg transform="scale(1,-1)" viewBox="0 0 5 5" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 4.7913519,3.0244664 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 5.0010679,2.7928393 L 5.0156169,0.23844982 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 4.8085546,0.00421882 L 4.1346977,8.822488e-6 A 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 3.9249817,0.23163592 l -0.01455,2.55438948 a 0.20774399,0.23233533 0.20022686 0 0 0.2070636,0.2342309 z"/>
    <path d="m 2.3026685,4.9997485 c 0.013054,-4.93e-4 0.026303,-0.00179 0.038974,-0.00367 a 0.41548798,0.46467067 0.20022686 0 0 0.349375,-0.4734803 c 0.00363,-0.6379822 0.449321,-1.333972 0.846806,-1.6370154 a 0.10387201,0.11616766 0.20022683 0 0 0.04533,-0.093674 L 3.5965423,0.44108678 A 0.10387201,0.11616766 0.20022683 0 0 3.5134437,0.3270351 C 3.4393718,0.31054085 3.3726995,0.29427924 3.3092171,0.2787802 A 3.5958408,4.0214923 0.20022685 0 0 2.454861,0.1638249 L 1.1051997,0.15539263 C 0.69865229,0.15285266 0.63632562,0.4085934 0.63546547,0.5596088 A 0.46534654,0.52043115 0.20022685 0 0 0.68283896,0.79088466 0.46700849,0.52228983 0.20022686 0 0 0.4704808,1.4864123 0.46783947,0.52321918 0.20022686 0 0 0.21269657,1.9506762 0.46243812,0.51717845 0.20022685 0 0 0.26776008,2.1996173 0.51935998,0.58083833 0.20022685 0 0 3.9256542e-6,2.7049256 0.51935998,0.58083833 0.20022685 0 0 0.51670335,3.287561 l 1.31071015,0.00819 a 0.051936,0.05808384 0.20022688 0 1 0.048253,0.076641 1.8040488,2.0176 0.20022685 0 0 -0.1129471,1.0230443 c 0.1119192,0.4570286 0.3441218,0.611708 0.5399491,0.6043122 z"/>
</svg>
```